# Is there anything wrong with voting on questions or answers if I don't participate on that site?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I have the +100 on any site I visit, so I can upvote on all sites in the network. This makes me wonder - is it okay to vote without participating on the site?

I could imagine that me drive-by-up-voting could cause issues, as I am introducing reputation to the site without knowing about the topic and without contributing anything.

I could compare it to printing Euros and dumping them in France without giving anything back to that country.

Answer (score 4):

Drive-by voting as you describe it has several effects and non-effects:

- If done irresponsibly, it may avoid that the best answer raises to the top.
- In most cases, you do not need to have experience with the site or the topic to be able to responsibly vote on posts, in particular answers. Upvotes essentially address two things:

  - Is the answer correct? Depending on the question, a good answer can provide sufficent arguments or references such that you can evaluate this yourself, even without being an expert on the subject. For example, (good) answers to many questions on Math.SE provide all the information you need to evaluate their correctness.
  - Is the answer well-explained? If you are a layman on the subject and understand the reasoning of an answer, it is pretty much well-explained by definition – you may even be in a better position to assess this quality in a question than an expert.

  Note that the above in particular applies to popular questions, as they often become popular due to being rather basic. Also note that even without non-drive-by upvotes, you have a lot of upvotes from people who did not test the answer or are sufficiently experienced to be certain about its correctness but instead vote on how well something is explained.
- Like regular upvotes, drive-by upvotes reward the poster for their efforts in writing a good post. Moreover, on many small sites, questions becoming viral are the only way to obtain certain badges, which are rewarding in turn. I partially keep posting elaborate answers to questions on small sites because ocassionaly one of them becomes viral and I can thus share my knowledge and thoughts with many people (and also get tons of reputation and badges) – even though I am often surprised by which posts become viral.
- It may cause users to get a lot of reputation and in particular the privileges associated with it from a single post (daily reputation limits only alleviate this effect). Even if this is a very good post by the site’s standards, this does not mean that the respective user can handle the responsibilities. One might argue, however, that this is an issue of the reputation system and not of drive-by voting.
- > I could compare it to printing Euros and dumping them in France without giving anything back to that country.

  There is no such thing as a balance of reputation; reputation gets generated all the time. I do not see this as something to worry about.

Taking the above together, I think that drive-by voting is a good thing, if you do it responsibly, and in particular do not upvote answers because you think that they are correct, but because they are sufficiently backed-up and explained so that even you as a layman can evaluate their truth.

Comment: +1 :) I'm also surprised which questions go viral on the network - for example this one is... simplistic: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/201554/

Comment: @Tim Just by looking at the selected answer... I'm at a loss for words.

Comment: @DominatorX I asked the question, it's just so inane... :P Then someone went and answered it! How did that get +25?!

Comment: @tim There might be another reason for the upvotes. When a question solicits good and elaborate answers I usually upvote the question too.

Comment: @guntbert yes, that does have the mark of a good question. I always upvote a question I answer, if it was good enough for me to spend a few minutes, they deserve the rep. It also reminds me not to answer bad questions.

Answer (score 2):

Without any rep at all I could have created an account on any site and asked a question, if the question is answered, accepting the answer adds 17 rep (15 to the answerer + 2 to me) to the site without necessarily knowing much about how the site works.

My experience is that I've had a problem which wasn't on a SO topic. Googling led me to another Stack Exchange site where I found a question almost identical to the one I would have written and an answer already provided. I followed the answer slavishly and it fixed my problem.

Because of the association bonus I can give the answerer 10 rep, almost as if I'd asked the question myself.

And I have contributed something, I've provided additional confirmation that the answer works.

Comment: My issue is I'm regularly upvoting on sites where the questions don't affect me and I don't ever post...

Comment: Why would you do that though? What's the point if neither the question nor the answer are interesting to you?

Comment: I said they don't affect me, not that they're not interesting, like this: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57450/which-insects-are-not-kosher

Comment: I'm not sure I'd feel qualified to vote on such an answer as I wouldn't know whether it was right. Or are you just voting on the question as interesting? If so is it on topic? Is it a duplicate? I suppose if you make some effort to establish those things then upvoting seems reasonable.